# How to swap two integers

Tags: java

Let's say I have variable holding 3 and another holding 5. I need to switch their values without another variable. How can I do it?

Comment: Why would you need to do that without using a separate variable? I can't see any reason for that other than for writing convoluted code. It's definitely not a real-world problem.

Comment: How **not** to do? Asks Yoda. By the way, Google, or even the search finction in the good old common Wikipeadia would have yielded you a nice and thorough answer...

Comment: XOR swap idiom for low-memory chips. But a mature compiler would optimize it.

Comment: Sounds like an interview question. Of course you would never do this in real code.

Comment: I saw that somewhere, promptly forgot it as complete useless....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using [bitwise XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR):

```
x ^= y;
y ^= x;
x ^= y;
```

This is known as the [XOR swap algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm) (that Wikipedia article goes into detail about how this works, so I suggest you read it).

However, this isn't particularly understandable (not to mention it only works on integral types), so in nearly all contexts using a temporary variable would be preferred:

```
int tmp = x;
x = y;
y = tmp;
```